# how i receive the session data in jquery webmethod

Tags: jquery

following is the code and i want to use return data in jquery ajax 
can anyone tell me i am new to this

```
            [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static string GetName(string Name)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {

            string Id = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCart"]);
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Products"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name from Product where Id in (" + Id + ")", cn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                 Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        return Name;
    }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: function NameofProduct() {
                $("[id*=btnCartDetail]").bind("click", function() {
                    alert("call");
                });
            }

Comment: above code is not working just to check the webmethod is working or not